# Show tooltip in dropdownlist items mouseover event

Tags: tooltip

I have one database with three columns named id.name, mobile_no.
I want to display mobile no as tooltip in dropdownlist items. Dropdownlist item showing name.
Tooltip showing mobile number which is in database so fetch from database.

How it is?

Comment: which platform, which language?!?

Answer (score 2):

Since you talk about a dropdownlist, I'm assuming this is ASP.NET. Here's how:

```vb
Private Sub loadDropDown  
    Dim personDataTable As DataTable
    Dim personDataRow As DataRow
    Dim personListItem As ListItem

    ' Data access stuff to get data from DB goes here

    For Each personDataRow In personDataTable.Rows
        personListItem = New ListItem
        With personListItem
            .Text = personDataRow.Item("Name").ToString
            .Value = personDataRow.Item("Id").ToString
            .Attributes.Add("title", personDataRow.Item("mobile_no").ToString)
        End With
        PeopleDropDownList.Items.Add(personListItem)
    Next
End Sub
```